# Fibered coproducts in $\mathsf{Set}$

Tags: category-theory

Following my not-entirely-successful attempt to define [fibered products in $\mathsf{Set}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577627/fibered-products-in-mathsf-set/577650#577650), I will attempt to define the fibered coproducts:

Let $A,B,C$ be sets, and let $\alpha\colon C\to A$ and $\beta\colon C\to B$. I want to find the fibered coproduct of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Let $Z$ be a set and let $f\colon A\to Z$ and $g\colon B\to Z$ with $f\alpha=g\beta$. By the universal property of disjoint unions, we can combine $f$ and $g$ to form a function $h\colon A\sqcup B\to Z$. Now because $f\alpha=g\beta$, $h(\iota_A(\alpha(c)))=h(\iota_B(\beta(c)))$, inducing a symmetric relation on $A\sqcup B$ whose transitive closure, $\sim$, is respected by any such $h$. Let $\pi\colon A\sqcup B\to (A\sqcup B)/\sim$ be the projection. Then $\phi_A:=\pi \iota_A$ and $\phi_B:=\pi\iota_B$ form the fibered coproduct:

By the universal property of the quotient, there is a unique $h'\colon (A\sqcup B)/\sim$ such that $h=h'\pi$ which occurs when $f=h\iota_A=h'\pi\iota_A=h'\phi_A$ and $g=h'\phi_B$.

---

Is this correct? Is there a better way?

Comment: Perhaps you should define $(A \sqcup B)/\sim$ before proving the universal property and introducing $f,g$ - but apart from that your proof looks good.

Comment: I think it's more succinct to simply describe the construction in terms of coproducts and coequalisers; this is basically the construction you use, but the exposition could be smoothed by making it explicit. But this may be a matter of taste on my part.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine, this is an exercise near the beginning of Paolo Aluffi's *Algebra: Chapter 0*, which is really about algebra, but weaves in some category theory. He doesn't introduce equalizers for another few hundred pages, and I don't know what they are yet. Can you explain them without the language of functors and limits that he uses?

Comment: Aha, gotcha. An equaliser of $f,g:A\rightrightarrows B$ is an object $C$ and a morphism $e:C\to A$ such that $f\circ e=g\circ e$ such that for any other arrow $h:C'\to A$ with $f\circ h=g\circ h$, there's a unique $e^*:C'\to C$ with $e\circ e^*=h$. It's the generalized notion of the subobject of $A$ on which $f$ and $g$ give the same outputs.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine, thank you kindly! I will try to write an answer to this question based on that concept. I figure a coequalizer just reverses all of those things?

Comment: Yep; the coequaliser generalizes the idea of quotienting by the least equivalence relation with $f(x)\sim g(x)$.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine, one last question (for now): Is there any standard notation for fibered products/coproducts? And what does that double arrow mean?

Comment: The double arrow is just to indicate two morphisms from and to the same objects succinctly. And I'm actually not sure about the notation for fibered thingies! I've seen $A\times_C B$, but I'm not sure that's used in general.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine, could you possibly check if the argument in my answer is correct?

Comment: I am at the same exercise from _Aluffi_. @dfeuer, could you please explain why you wrote "by any such $h$"? Once we fix a solution $A \sqcup B$ (along with $\iota_A$ and $\iota_B$) to the universal property of disjoint unions, isn't $h$ determined uniquely?

Comment: @doodle, it's been a couple years, so I don't actually remember. Sorry. I actually reviewed some related material recently, but not that particular exercise.

Comment: @dfeuer, quite understandable :) I only noticed the date after I commented. This post was still helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument I gave essentially contains a sketch of a proof that coequalizers in $\mathsf{Set}$ are as described in Malice Vidrine's comment. All that remains is to show that a category with (binary) coproducts and coequalizers has (binary) fibered coproducts. The general finite and infinite cases look to be about the same.

Let $\alpha\colon C\to A$ and $\beta\colon C\to B$ as before. Let $e\colon A\amalg B\to D$ be the coequalizer of $i_A \alpha$ and $i_B \beta$. By the definition of coproduct, $hi_A=f$ and $hi_B=g$. By the definition of coequalizer, $(ei_A)\alpha=e(i_A\alpha)=e(i_B\beta)=(ei_B)\beta$. I wish to show that in fact $ei_A\colon A\to D$ and $ei_B\colon B\to D$ form the fibered coproduct of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Let $f\colon A\to Z$, $g\colon B\to Z$, and $f\alpha=g\beta$. Then by the definition of coproduct, there is a unique $h\colon A\amalg B\to Z$ such that $f=hi_A$ and $g=hi_B$. Then by the definition of coequalizer, there is a unique $h'\colon D\to Z$ such that $h'e=h$, so $h'$ is the unique morphism from $D$ to $Z$ such that $f=h'(ei_A)$ and $g=h'(ei_B)$.

Does this look right?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: @MaliceVidrine, thanks again! Are there any trick to make the presentation smoother?

Comment: Don't think so, I think that was a pretty good presentation.