# Notation for "parallel" morphisms in a diagram

Tags: notation, category-theory

Suppose $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon A\to B$ are possibly-distinct morphisms. How do I stick them both in a diagram (along with, e.g., their (co)equalizer) without suggesting that they are equal?

Comment: The notation is just you put two distinct arrows between $A$ and $B$ (it's often done with two straight lines above one another). Are you asking how to TeX it?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein, this came up in the context of (my own answer to) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578414/fibered-coproducts-in-mathsfset/578771#578771, where the two morphisms are each composite, so one might glance at it and think the whole diagram is supposed to commute, when in fact everything *except that part* is supposed to commute.

Comment: I always use \rightrightarrows: $\rightrightarrows$

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, could you explain what you do with them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple cases (such as for (co)equalizers) you can get away with simply showing them beside each other. Even if you assert that the diagram commutes, that will not be understood as requiring equality between two morphisms that are explicitly shown and named in the diagram.

If the case is not simple, you can still draw the diagram (as an illustration of the situation) as long as you don't claim it commutes. You'll have to specify equations by saying that such-and-such specific *subdiagrams* commute.

... or perhaps it may be clearer just to duplicate an object in the diagram, such that the morphisms are not parallel anymore.

Comment: How do you represent the duplication? Do you just reuse the same letter?

Comment: @dfeuer: Write the name of the object in two different places on the paper?

Answer (score 4):

Freyd and Ščedrov *Categories, Allegories* (Elsevier, 1990) use a "puncture mark" in a diagram to indicate this.

[image: Definition of "puncture mark" notation]

(Page 11.)

This covers your application as a special case.  For example, the definition of an equalizer involves $f,g: A\to B$ which are not necessarily equal, and $e: E\to A$ with $f\circ e = g\circ e$.  Freyd and Ščedrov represent this situation in the leftmost of the following set of diagrams:

[image: Equalizer diagrams, with punctures]

(Page 42.)  The two arrows $A\to B$ have a puncture mark between, which removes the assertion of the arrows' equality that the diagram would normally be presumed to be requiring.  But since “the puncture mark removes only one equation”, equality of the two paths $f\circ e$  and $g\circ e$ is still asserted.

I don't know how widespread this notation is, however.